# Read looping variable inside nested function Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

```
for (var j=0; j<charts.length; j++){
    var chart = charts[j].chartImage;
    chart["export"].capture({}, function() {
        this.toPNG({}, function(data) {
            saved_charts[j] = data;
            charts_remaining--;

            if (charts_remaining == 0) {
                console.log(saved_charts[0]);
                console.log(saved_charts[1]);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

my problem on saved_charts[j] it can't read the j variable and it says "mutable variable is accessible from closure". is there any other way so i can get the j variable? i know i can use array.push() but for some reason the code generate data value in irregular way which doesn't return data value accordingly. i think it's because some data is too large so the function return smaller data first. sorry i'm still having hard time understanding Javasript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should works

```
for (let j=0; j<charts.length; j++){
```

if `let` keyword is not supported, this is the classic way:

```
for (var j=0; j<charts.length; j++){
    var chart = charts[j].chartImage;
    (function(j) {
        chart["export"].capture({}, function() {
            this.toPNG({}, function(data) {
                saved_charts[j] = data;
            })
        })
    })(j);
}
```

Comment: my javascript version is not supported :(

Comment: @ArdiSugiarto modified my answer. try it again =)

Comment: this works!!! thank you! i have stuck in this problem all day. but i have updated my javascript version though, will it cause any problems?

Comment: mostly it won't be a problem to upgrade javascript. and both way are equally solid.

Answer (score 1):

In old JS environments you can create a closure (with IIFE) to "freeze" the variable. Like this:

```
for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++){
    (function(j) {
        setTimeout(function () {console.log(j)}, 10);
    })(j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (var j=0; j<charts.length; j++){
    var chart = charts[j].chartImage;
    (function(p){
        chart["export"].capture({}, function() {
          (function(q){
            this.toPNG({}, function(data) {
                saved_charts[q] = data;
                charts_remaining--;

                if (charts_remaining == 0) {
                    console.log(saved_charts[0]);
                    console.log(saved_charts[1]);
                }
            })
          })(p)
        })
    })(j)
}
```

or

Try this

```
for (var j=0; j<charts.length; j++){
    var chart = charts[j].chartImage;
    (function(p){
        chart["export"].capture({}, function() {
            this.toPNG({}, function(data) {
                saved_charts[p] = data;
                charts_remaining--;

                if (charts_remaining == 0) {
                    console.log(saved_charts[0]);
                    console.log(saved_charts[1]);
                }
            })
        })
    })(j)
}
```

Comment: Oops my mistake wait I fix

Comment: The inner closure is unnecessary.

Comment: Okay remove that